# How to apply OR condition on Element nodes in XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to write one *common* xpath that selects either the `<input>` or the `<textarea>` element based on the text in `<h3>`.

```
<form>
  <legend>
    <h3> ... >Testing</h3>
  </legend>
  <div>
    <input ...>
  </div>
</form>

<form>
  <legend>
    <h3> ... >Testing</h3>
  </legend>
  <div>
    <textarea class='textAreaBox' ...</textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have 2 XPaths,
`//h3[text()='Testing']/parent::legend/following-sibling::div/input` selects the `<input>` element and
`//h3[text()='Testing']/parent::legend/following-sibling::div/textarea` select the `<textarea>` element

To select either of these, the only way I could think of is

```
//h3[text()='Testing']/parent::legend/following-sibling::div/input | //h3[text()='Testing']/parent::legend/following-sibling::div/textarea
```

Is there a better xpath than this one?
I know you can use OR on attributes but how can I use OR condition to select a Element node i.e `<input>` or `<textarea>` element?

Comment: The text in <h3> determines which of these 2 element would appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following `xpath` to identify.

```
//h3[text()='Testing']/following::*[self::input[1] | self::textarea[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
//form[legend/h3[text()='Testing']]/div/*[self::input | self::textarea]
```

Check the test [here](http://xpather.com/HqVwMF3g).

Answer (score 1):

```
//h3[text()='Testing']/following::*[name()='input' or name()='textarea']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using `or`, you can select all children with `*` and use the `self` axis to filter in the predicate:

`//h3[text()='Testing']/parent::legend/following-sibling::div/*[self::textarea or self::input]`

And to reduce your number of axes overall for readability:

`//form[legend/h3='Testing']/div/*[self::textarea or self::input]`